# How do I get Spring to print out all the injected bean information?

Tags: spring

Once Spring container started, is it possible to programmatically print out all the injected info including bean id, dependencies etc. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there tooling to visualize a live Spring application context?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425794/is-there-tooling-to-visualize-a-live-spring-application-context)

Comment: @EngineerDollery I am looking at a programmatic solution.

Comment: Cool -- duplicate close vote retracted. Now, if you'll just read [ask], and show us what you've tried I'll be happy to retract the 'hasn't even tried to solve the problem themselves' close vote ;)

Comment: Also, why would you want to do that when there are plenty of tools, available for free I think (or on trial otherwise), such as IntelliJ, which will do it for you any time you ask.

Comment: ps: sorry -- too many comments. If you are *really* interested, look at: ApplicationContextAware

Comment: @EngineerDollery My work is based on a large, very complex commercial platform built on spring. There are a lot constrains including choice of IDES. My best shot is to do it programmatically.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with that comment. However, you still haven't worked out how to use SO effectively. Again, I'll ask you to read [ask]. You probably aren't going to get a good answer unless you expend some energy solving the problem yourself and show us what you've tried. We're not here to do your work for you, but to help you when you're stuck trying something unfamiliar.